# problem with deleting one element from array in with update pull

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am using mongoose and express as my backend, I am trying delete one array element from an orders array inside a single Mongodb document. Is this possible? I have searched online but I only found how to delete all elements with a filter or pop the first or last element in the array.

Currently I am doing this in the backend however this deletes every orders element with item_id equal to data.response[0].item_id.

```
user.updateOne({ "username": data.username },{"$pull": { "orders": {"item_id": data.response[0].item_id}}},{safe: true });
```

This line of code deletes both elements inside orders when the item_id is 1 however I only want it to delete the first element it finds with item_id: 1

Example Mongodb document part of Users collection

```
{
        "_id": "60a906402342852b483341a6",
        "username": "qwer",
        "password": "qwer",
        "orders": [
            {
                "_id": "609cf4d4e4ecce2348139686",
                "item_id": 1,
                "item_name": "toothbrush",
                "item_price": 28,
                "item_category": "dental",
                "item_currency": "$",
                "item_description": "standard toothbrush",
                "item_image": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1704/0849/products/ToothBrushTeal_bc4c6c15-cf79-4bb5-87cc-28109b5e7605_1024x1024.jpg?v=1607029152"
            },
            {
                "_id": "609cf4d4e4ecce2348139686",
                "item_id": 1,
                "item_name": "toothbrush",
                "item_price": 28,
                "item_category": "dental",
                "item_currency": "$",
                "item_description": "standard toothbrush",
                "item_image": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1704/0849/products/ToothBrushTeal_bc4c6c15-cf79-4bb5-87cc-28109b5e7605_1024x1024.jpg?v=1607029152"
            }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may want to check this forum https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/pull-only-one-item-in-an-array-of-instance-in-mongodb/12928
Using an aggregation update, as the first answer shows.
Your code should be something like this:

```
user.updateOne({ "username": data.username },[ 
{ $set: { 
     orders: {
         $let: {
             vars: { ix: { $indexOfArray: [ "$orders", data.response[0].item_id ] } },
             in: { $concatArrays: [
                       { $slice: [ "$orders", 0, "$$ix"] },
                       [ ],
                       { $slice: [ "$orders", { $add: [ 1, "$$ix" ] }, { $size: "$orders" } ] }
                  ]
             }
        }
    }
}}],{safe: true });
```